# How to implement move scale photo option for edit photo just like in contacts add photo option

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

In my **iPhone app** i **have add photo option**, in that i added photos `from library as well as captured images` also..

When i open image picker to add/capture image it just display retake & use photo.

When i tapped on use it displays as it is image in image view

but **`i need to display my selected crop,`** just like add photo in contacts app in iphone

**I did** it by set **`self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;`**

But **whenever i want to edit the image, i need to get back the original image but not the scaled/cropped image in the image picker to edit again**

Comment: Crystal Ball Answers: [UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007069-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have to set allowEditing of UIImagePickerController to YES,
Try the below:

```
- (IBAction)takePicture:(id)sender {
UIImagePickerController *imagePicer = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    [imagePicer setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
} else {
    [imagePicer setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
}

// This will sets the editing mode after taking of picking image from image picker

[imagePicer setAllowsEditing:YES];
[imagePicer setDelegate:self];

//place image picker on the screen
[self presentViewController:imagePicer animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

If you want to use the image that after editing, please change "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" to "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage", that's it!!

Comment: where we have used UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage ?

Comment: In UIImagePickerController delegate method - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info and get image as UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];